# Disks utility says SMART is not supported, is there a workaround or another way to troubleshoot?

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, smart

I am using the Live USB to troubleshoot a troublesome hard drive.

I want to run the self-test but as you can see in the image below that it says "SMART is not supported" and because of this I can't run the test. Is it because it's in Raid configuration?

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to make is so SMART *is* supported?

Are there other tools on the Live USB to troubleshoot my troublesome hard drive?

Comment: What hard drive ? manufacturer please ...

Comment: @bodhi I want to say it's a Western Digital VelociRaptor. Don't worry about it though, I solved my underlying issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fooling around with Disks I found a benchmark option.

The benchmark can be used to test the read/write speed even if SMART is not supported, this is useful in determining if the hard drive is slow or the installation of your OS is messed up.

1. Click the drive.
2. Click the gears icon.
3. Click "Benchmark..." to benchmark.

For what it's worth my troublesome hard drive has a read/write speed of 8MB/s / 6MB/s, compared to a working one that is closer to 80MB/s. This answers my underlying issue which was trying to figure out if something was wrong with my hard drive or my Windows installation.